# Tensorflow session run not working with mean_squared_error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am sure there is something obvious that I am overlooking but when I attempt to get the mean squared error with tensorflow I am getting an error message.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([3, -0.5, 2, 7])
b = tf.constant([2.5, 0.0, 2, 8])
c = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(c))
```

with the error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value mean_squared_error/count
     [[Node: mean_squared_error/count/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](mean_squared_error/count)]]
```

But printing c on its own does not yield an error:

```
print c

(<tf.Tensor 'mean_squared_error/value:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'mean_squared_error/update_op:0' shape=() dtype=float32>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23c218785eac5bfe737eec4f8081fd0ef8e0684d/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L48) the following will work

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
a = tf.constant([3, -0.5, 2, 7])
b = tf.constant([2.5, 0.0, 2, 8])
c = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(c))
```

Please understand that this is a streaming operation. Do not mix it up with the function [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error).

Comment: Hi Patwie, could you edit your answer to briefly explain what a streaming operation is? Why does Tensorflow have both `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` and `tf.metrics.mean_squared_error` when the former seems to be the better choice as you then dont need to add a local variables initializer.

Comment: They are two different things. The tf.losses is just doing what you expect it should do: compute a metric for the current batch. The tf.metrics allow to accumulate information over entire streams of data, eg you cannot compute the accuracy on imagenet in one sess.run call (like tf.losses) you need tf.metrics in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize variables before accessing them , 
to initilze :

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([3, -0.5, 2, 7])
b = tf.constant([2.5, 0.0, 2, 8])
c = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer() <--
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) <---
print(sess.run(c))
```

Comment: I still get the error `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value mean_squared_error/count
  [[Node: mean_squared_error/count/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](mean_squared_error/count)]]`

Comment: I have added it in the same order as you have posted it. I restarted the kernel on jupyter-notebook but I am still getting the same error

Comment: I get the same error @Patwie with InteractiveSession

Comment: HI @Patwie ,Ali, Do you get the same errors when you try to run the code?